# closing two successive tabs from google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome.

When a search page is opened on the target site, a content script is injected which sends a request to the background page to open a detailPage in a new tab.  When the detailPage is opened a content script is injected which sends a request to the background page to open the messagePage in a new tab.  When the messagePage is opened a content script is injected that sends a message and closes the messagePage tab.  So far, so good.  Focus is returned to the detailPage tab.

But how to close the detailPage?  The script that was in the messagePage is gone.  The script in the detailPage is idle.  I suppose background has to close both the detailPage tab and the messagePage tab.  I tried two successive chrome.tabs.remove commands but this code just hangs:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cmd == "closeMessage") {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        });
    }
});
```

It seems to me this has to be a part of the action upon receiving the "closeMessage" cmd.  But how?  And if not, how?

I understand that the tab.id of the sender is returned as sender.tab.id.  Can't I just access this and use it to close the detailPage?

Comment: Pop up a message asking the user to press the little X in the corner of the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create those two tabs from a background page - save their ids. Then you can easily close them later.

```
var detailTabId = null;
var msgTabId = null;
...
chrome.tabs.create({url: "detail.html"}, function(tab){
    detailTabId = tab.id;
});
...
chrome.tabs.create({url: "message.html"}, function(tab){
    msgTabId = tab.id;
});
...
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cmd == "closeMessage") {
        chrome.tabs.remove(detailTabId);
        chrome.tabs.remove(msgTabId);
    }
});
```